# Analyze container file system on kubernetes after it exits/crashes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, crash, containers, postmortem-debugging

Perhaps a silly question with no sense:

In a kubernetes deployment (or minikube), when a pod container crashes, i would like to analyze the file system at that moment. In this way, i could see core dumps or any other useful information.

I know that i could mount a volume or PVC to get core dumps from a host-defined core pattern location, and i also could get logs by mean a rsyslog sidecar or any other way, but i still would like to do "post-mortem" analysis if possible. I assume that kubernetes should provide (but i don't know how, that's the reason of my question) some mechanism to do this forensics tasks easing the life to all of us, because in a production system we could need to analyze killed/exited containers.

I tried playing directly with *docker run* without *--rm* option, but can't get nothing useful from inspection to get useful information or recreate the file system in last moment that had the container alive.

Thank u very much!

Comment: For debugging purposes and in general to understand why a pod terminated, your app can write to /dev/termination-log .. then as usual check this message using kubectl describe pod .... You can change this default using `terminationMessagePath` and `terminationMessagePolicy` on the pod spec [Refer link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/#writing-and-reading-a-termination-message) .. and we can use `kubectl logs podname -c container --previous` comand to check last restart logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When a pod container crashes, i would like to analyze the file system at that moment.

**POD (Containers) natively use non-persistent storage. 
When a container exits/terminates, so does the container’s storage.**

POD (Container) can be connected to storage that is external. This will allows for the storage of persistent data (you can configure volume mount as path to core dump etc..), since this external storage is not removed when a container is stopped/killed will help you with more flexibility to analysis the file system. Configuring container file system storage with commonly used file systems such as NFS .. etc ..

Comment: Thanks, i though that some kind of temporary persistency existed for exited containers, just in case user wants to analyze.

Comment: If you do not explicitly define a persistent volume then at Max you can last exit logs for a container but filesystem state afraid not. You can get exit logs for last terminated container using 'kubectl logs podname -c containername --previous'

Comment: You can use a basic hostPath config for development and testing on local cluster else use a NFS alike solution for production grade cluster